# Calculate dot product without the use of angles

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry, inner-products

In a book called *Introduction to tensor analysis and the calculus of moving surfaces* equation (2.6) gives a formula to calculate the dot product between two vectors in terms of length alone. That formula is the following:

$$
 \mathbf{U}\cdot{V} = \frac{\left| \mathbf{U} + \mathbf{V} \right|^2 - \left| \mathbf{U} - \mathbf{V} \right|^2}{4}
$$

I suppose then that the above shall be equal to

$$
 \mathbf{U}\cdot\mathbf{V} = |\mathbf{U}||\mathbf{V}|\cos{\alpha}
$$

where $\alpha$ is the angle between $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$. How can it be proved that both identities are equal?

Comment: I don't think you'd really prove both identities equal. It's more straightforward to show that each identity holds independently of the other, which gives you the equality.

Comment: Hint : $$(a+b)^2 - (a-b)^2 = 4ab$$

Comment: @platty Indeed, they hold independently of each other