# Is the following a formula for expressing a dot product in terms of length?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, inner-products

I've come across the following formula and I've been told that it's expressing a dot product in terms of length, but I can't find any sources or derivations for it online.

$$⟨u,v⟩ =  \frac{|u+v|^2 - |u|^2 - |v|^2 }{2}$$

I found some similar-looking [formulae](https://opentextbc.ca/calculusv3openstax/chapter/the-dot-product#fs-id1163724085758), but nothing exactly of this form. Can you tell me how to derive this? I know about finding the Pythagorean length, but stumped to find the exact formula above.

There is also this question which seems to be almost the same, but again, it's not quite there.

[Calculate dot product without the use of angles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038573/calculate-dot-product-without-the-use-of-angles)

And in a comment to that question, the hint

$$(a+b)^2−(a−b)^2=4ab$$

Comment: $\langle u+v, u+v\rangle=\langle u, u\rangle+\langle v, v\rangle+2\langle u, v\rangle$, $\ \langle x, x\rangle=|x|^2$.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Thanks

Comment: This is basically the law of cosines, isn't it?

Comment: For a space over complex scalars rather than real ones, [it's a bit different](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607400/polarization-identity-for-complex-scalars).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a polarization identity, it can be shown by rewriting the norms in terms of the inner product.  In this case,

\begin{align*}
|u+v|^2 - |u|^2 - |v|^2 &= \langle u+v,u+v \rangle - |u|^2 - |v|^2 \\
&= \langle u,u\rangle + 2 \langle u,v \rangle + \langle v,v \rangle - |u|^2 - |v|^2 \\
&= |u|^2 + 2 \langle u,v \rangle + |v|^2 - |u|^2 - |v|^2 \\
&= 2 \langle u,v \rangle.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the name of it.

Comment: I was actually reading a PDF before posting, and this is in it. The lesson here, is that I just need to pay more attention. https://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~fjones/chap1.pdf#page=25